# what is the exact use of auto implemented properties

Tags: c#, .net, properties

May be its a duplicate question.
I did search about this and referred these Articles

- [use of properties vs backing field inside owner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457010/use-of-properties-vs-backing-field-inside-owner-class),
- [should i prefer properties with or without private fields](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/161166/should-i-prefer-properties-with-or-without-private-fields),
- [Properties Matter](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx).

The point i understood was,

1. Access like making field read only
2. We can include some logics in
3. setter/getter used for data binding

What I really want to clear was,

```
public class Employee {
    public string strName;
}

public class Employee {
    public string strName {get;set;} 
}
```

**My questions:**

1. Whats the difference between this two implementations
2. Is there any place ( i mean actual scenario) where we can justify a need for  auto implemented properties instead the first implementation as shown above as first.

**UPDATE**

I know its a duplicate question and i mentioned it. Please consider my 2nd point in questions i asked.
what the answer precisely ?
I couldn't understand that.

Whether its a good practice or what is the need if i do not have any logic to set that value ?

Fine thank you all for replying. I got it now clear. Since i am very new i cant grasp it. But now i got the point. Sorry for wasting all your time.

Comment: Actually, the three points that you list in the beginning are three things that *cannot* be done with auto-implemented properties, or at least not in as flexible or complete a way as with fully written properties.

Comment: the choice is auto or manually implemented properties, just exposing a member variable is wrong. Think about the consequences of having to put some logic around setting name in a mature code base. Oh and stop with the hungarian notation.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Thanks for reply. Fine, then is there any place where we can justify the need for aip over the normal implementation as i asked in the last part

Comment: Here is a SO answer that is helpful and address your questions to some point: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5203341/2777098

Comment: Auto implementaion is syntactic sugar, just stops you having to write a getter and setter for each property, nothing else

Comment: @DaveHillier i already mentioned its a duplicate. i was asked for a scenario where i need to use auto implemeted properties instead the first implementation as shown in my question. I need that point to be clear. So why i asked this question

Comment: It is covered - it is to making your interfaces robust to change. Changing a field to a property is not backwards compatible. Properties are considered the best way to expose a public interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a field inside a class is not a good idea. using properties allows you to [encapsulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) your data better. and when you just want to have a field accessible without any logic in you class then you can use automatic properties.

there are many scenarios that using a field inside your class makes things go wrong and harder as your software evolve.

for example: assume you have

```
public class C
{
    public int Value;
}
```

in your code base.

then suddenly you realize that `Value` can not be set to zero. Then you have to make `Value` private and provide a `SetValue()` and `GetValue()` method. This is easy. but wait, how you gonna handle all other codes that relies on `Value` now?

but think about this one

```
public class C
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

now it just needs a backing field like `_value` and implementing the `setter` and `getter`.

Comment: Your example doesn't make much sense.
In a case where you want to have a property that can be get/set publicly, your example does not give a reason why the auto-implemented getter/setter are better.

If you originally wrote the code as a property and subsequently changed it to have an implemented getter/setter, it would still work

Answer (score 5):

With auto implemented properties you can do

```
public class Employee {
 public string StrName {get; private set;} 
}
```

And make an external read-only, but internal settable property.  Which is something you can't do with your public variable

Comment: Shouldn't public property start with a capital letter as per conventions?

Comment: @AniketThakur Of course it should.  I blame the younger me for that!

Comment: I think it's the `private` in `{ get; private set; }` that's the secret sauce for me. That's precisely what IDE0032 was trying to get me not to do in this case. Now I can, with minimal code, set up a property that's settable within the class, but read-only for all practical purposes outside...