# "this" operator not working

Tags: c#, get, set, this

Every time I use `this._Something`, my `this.` is light blue and it has green underline. And I cant get value 101 after F5. Instead, I get value 0. Any help ?

```
class Student
{
    private int _ID;

    public void SetID(int Id)
    {
        if (Id <= 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("It is not a Valid ID");
            this._ID = Id;
        }
    }

    public int GetID()
    {
        return this._ID;
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Student C1 = new Student();
        C1.SetID(101);
        Console.WriteLine("Student ID = {0}", C1.GetID());
    }
}
```

Comment: `this._ID = Id;` should be outside the `if {}` else its never written to.  Hover over the underlined symbol/look in the left margin and VS will tell you what its whining about.

Comment: Ok, but why is it lightblue in my Visual Studio ?

Comment: @ZvezdaBre see my answer

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning _ID only if (Id <= 0), change your code to:

```
public void SetID(int Id)
{
    if (Id <= 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("It is not a Valid ID");
    }
    _ID = Id;
}
```

Your `this` call is lightblue, because VS is telling you that you don't need to use it here. You don't have local variable with same name. Read more about `this` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250/when-do-you-use-the-this-keyword)

BTW you should read about properties with backing fields, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457010/use-of-properties-vs-backing-field-inside-owner-class)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest redesigning *both* `get` and `set` methods into single *property*; you have no need to mimic *Java* in *C#*:

```
 class Student {
   private int _ID; 

   public int ID {
     get {
       return _ID;
     }
     set {
       // input validation:
       // be exact, do not throw Exception but ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
       // it's argument that's wrong and it's wrong because it's out of range 
       if (value <= 0) 
         throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", "Id must be positive");

       _ID = value;
     }
   }
 }
```

...

```
public static void Main()
{
    Student C1 = new Student();
    C1.ID = 101;
    Console.WriteLine("Student ID = {0}", C1.ID);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
class Student
{
    private int _ID;

    public int ID
    {
        get{ return _ID;}

        set {
            if (value <= 0)
                throw new Exception("It is not a Valid ID");
            _ID = value;
           }

    }


}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Student C1 = new Student();
        C1.ID=101;
        Console.WriteLine("Student ID = {0}", C1.ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks . I forgot it.